# Sorting data from a table

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, psycopg2

I'm working on a new version of a module and I need to create a new table for that, but I'm facing a little issue that is driving me crazy.

Here is my relevant python code:

```
import psycopg2, sys, psycopg2.extras, time

order = 4419

try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', database='DB01', user='odoo', password='******')
cur = con.cursor()
po_lines = 'SELECT pos_order_line.id FROM public.pos_order_line, public.product_template ' \
           'WHERE pos_order_line.product_id = product_template.id AND  pos_order_line.order_id = %s '\
           'AND (product_template.pos_categ_id != 5 AND product_template.pos_categ_id != 6)' \
           'ORDER BY pos_order_line.id ASC'
po_lines2 = 'SELECT pos_order_line.id, pos_order_line.order_id, product_template.name, pos_order_line.qty, product_template.pos_categ_id ' \
            'FROM public.pos_order_line, public.product_template  ' \
            'WHERE pos_order_line.product_id = product_template.id AND  pos_order_line.id = %s ' \
            'ORDER BY pos_order_line.id ASC'

cur.execute(po_lines,[order]); fetch_lines = cur.fetchall()
dish = ''; instr = []; kot = 0; dp = 0
print fetch_lines
for line in fetch_lines:
    cur.execute(po_lines2, [line]); pos_lines = cur.fetchone()
    if pos_lines[2].startswith('#'):
        instr.insert(1, pos_lines[2][2:]); kot = 1
    elif pos_lines[2].startswith('----'):
        dp = 1
    else:
        dish = pos_lines[2]
        kot = 0; instr = []
        if dp == 1:
            instr.insert(0, '!SERVIR DEPOIS!'); dp = 0
    if dish != pos_lines[2]:
        print 'Ordem: ', order, ' - Prato:', dish, ' - Instr:', instr, 'qt: ', pos_lines[3],'kot: ', kot, 'dp status:', dp

except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
print 'Error %s' % e
sys.exit(1)

finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

Starting from a query I have:

```
ID     ORDER PRODUCT                    QTY     CAT
12811  4419  "Crudo GR"                 1.0       1
12812  4419  "Salame e Grana GR"        1.0       1
12813  4419  "---- servir depois ----"  1.0       7
12814  4419  "Nutella Ban GR"           1.0       3
12815  4419  "# Cortar em dois"         1.0       7
```

Resuming all product line (pos_lines[2]) not starting with '#' or with '----' need to be placed on a variable 'instr' until the var 'dish' changes.
All the line are correctly read because if I put a print statement at the end of all IF cycles I can see how the variables are filled:

> 1 Ordem:  4419  - Prato: Crudo GR  - Instr: [] qt:  1.0 kot:  0 dp status: 0
>
> 2 Ordem:  4419  - Prato: Salame e Grana GR  - Instr: [] qt:  1.0 kot:  0 dp status: 0
>
> 3 Ordem:  4419  - Prato: Salame e Grana GR  - Instr: [] qt:  1.0 kot:  0 dp status: 1
>
> 4 Ordem:  4419  - Prato: Nutella Ban GR  - Instr: ['!SERVIR DEPOIS!'] qt:  1.0 kot:  0 dp status: 0
>
> 5 Ordem:  4419  - Prato: Nutella Ban GR  - Instr: ['!SERVIR DEPOIS!', 'Cortar em dois'] qt:  1.0 kot:  0 dp status: 0

I've numerated the lines just to show how the problem is: lines 2 and 4 should be hidden because are just intermediate steps.
Then the results I need should be:

```
ID     ORDER PRODUCT              INSTR                              QTY     
12811  4419  "Crudo GR"                                               1.0       
12812  4419  "Salame e Grana GR"                                    1.0       
12814  4419  "Nutella Ban GR"     "!SERVIR DEPOIS! Cortar em dois"          1.0
```

Could someone gently tell me where is the error in my code and how to put the correct print statement?
Please note I'm relatively new on Python, have mercy.

Thanks.

**Edit: solved with a more simple approach based on the hints of Merlin.**

The code wrote by Merlin is complicated to setup for me due to the many variant I have. I rewrote part of my script in a more basic way.
In this version I've reverted the lines of the fetch to grab and add to the respective line all the instructions (#) I need after the product in a temp table. Then I reversed again the lines to check if there is a line '----' before a product and add to the respective product, last I wrote to the final table. This script is much simple to read (for a newbie like me) and avoid the use of 'operator' module simply reversing a table with [::-1].

```
TableTemp = []; newTable = []; Instr = ''

for line in fetch_lines[::-1]:
    if line[2].startswith('#') or line[2].startswith('----'):
        if line[2].startswith('#'):
            Instr = line[2][2:]+' | '+ Instr
        if line[2].startswith('----'):
            TableTemp.append((line[0], line[1], line[2], '', line[3], line[4]))
    else:
        TableTemp.append((line[0],line[1],line[2], Instr, line[3], line[4]))
        Instr = ''

for line in TableTemp[::-1]:
    if line[2].startswith('----'):
        Instr = '!SERVIR DEPOIS! | '
    else:
        newTable.append((line[0],line[1],line[2], Instr+line[3][:-3], line[4], line[5]))
        Instr = ''
```

Result:

Inner fetch:

```
(13264, 4558, 'Funghi GR', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13265, 4558, '# + Champinhons', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13266, 4558, '# + Alface', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13267, 4558, '# - R\xc3\xbacola', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13268, 4558, 'Formaggi GR', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13269, 4558, '# Cortar em dois', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13270, 4558, '---- servir depois ----', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13271, 4558, 'Nutella GR', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13272, 4558, '# Cortar em dois', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13273, 4558, '---- servir depois ----', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13274, 4558, 'Nutella Mor MD', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13275, 4558, '# Para Levar', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
```

Output table:

```
(13264, 4558, 'Funghi GR', '+ Champinhons | + Alface | - R\xc3\xbacola', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13268, 4558, 'Formaggi GR', 'Cortar em dois', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13271, 4558, 'Nutella GR', '!SERVIR DEPOIS! | Cortar em dois', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
(13274, 4558, 'Nutella Mor MD', '!SERVIR DEPOIS! | Para Levar', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 11')
```

Comment: If I put a print statement at the on the loop it prints all, including the intermediate lines. I need to print just when the var dish changes.

Comment: The lines are correctly read. The problem is how to show just a line when the var 'dish' changes.

Comment: I've edited the question with some infos @merlin. Could you explain with a code example what you mean? I've undestood the concept but the fetch need to be looped.  As I wrote I'm new on Python.

Comment: @jcoppens, you are assuming google searches the tags. Nope.. People read the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems you have two tables. This way you only making 2 trips to the database vs many.

Do a fetches -- to get data from tables

Table one

```
ID     ORDER PRODUCT                    QTY     CAT
12811  4419  "Crudo GR"                 1.0       1
12812  4419  "Salame e Grana GR"        1.0       1
12813  4419  "---- servir depois ----"  1.0       7
12814  4419  "Nutella Ban GR"           1.0       3
12815  4419  "# Cortar em dois"         1.0       7
```

get the data as table,

```
newTable = [] 
Intr = ''

    #Added something like
    #http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/12/how-to-sort-table-by-columns-in-python/
        #import operator
       #fetch_lines = sorted(fetch_lines, key=operator.itemgetter(col))

#Sort table so looks like this

    # ID     ORDER PRODUCT                    QTY     CAT
   # 12815  4419  "# Cortar em dois"         1.0       7
   # 12813  4419  "---- servir depois ----"  1.0       7
   # 12811  4419  "Crudo GR"                 1.0       1
   # 12812  4419  "Salame e Grana GR"        1.0       1
   # 12814  4419  "Nutella Ban GR"           1.0       3


for i,line in enumerate(fetch_lines):
    if line[2].startswith('#') or line[2].startswith('----'): 
        # Within this if statement you can make adjustment to text item
        if line[2].startswith('#')
           Intr =  Intr + " Cortar em dois"
        if line[2].startswith('----')
           Intr =  '!SERVIR DEPOIS!' + Intr
    if i == len(fetch_lines) -1:
        newTable.append([line[0], ....., Intr ,  ...])
    if i < len(fetch_lines)
        newTable.append([line[0], ....., '',  ...])
print table


   #Then sort by first column  so table look right 
           #table = sorted( newTable, key=operator.itemgetter(col))

#ID     ORDER PRODUCT              INSTR                              QTY     
#12811  4419  "Crudo GR"                                               1.0       
#12812  4419  "Salame e Grana GR"                                    1.0       
#12814  4419  "Nutella Ban GR"     "!SERVIR DEPOIS! Cortar em dois"          1.0
```

Try This to place Intr in last row:

```
newTable = [] 
Intr     = ''
LineCt   = 0


for line in fetch_lines:
    if line[2].startswith('#') or line[2].startswith('----'): 
        # Within this if statement you can make adjustment to text item
        if line[2].startswith('#'):
           Intr =  Intr + " Cortar em dois"
           LineCt +=1
        if line[2].startswith('----'):
           Intr =  '!SERVIR DEPOIS!' + Intr
           LineCt +=1   

for i,line in enumerate(fetch_lines):
    if line[2].startswith('#') or line[2].startswith('----'): pass        
    elif i == len(fetch_lines) - LineCt:
        newTable.append([line[0],line[1], line[2], Intr , "" ])
        Intr     = ''
    elif i < len(fetch_lines):
        newTable.append([line[0],line[1],line[2], '', "" ])        

print Intr        
for e in newTable: print e
```

Output:

```
  [12811, 4419, 'Crudo GR', '', '']
    [12812, 4419, 'Salame e Grana GR', '', '']
    [12814, 4419, 'Nutella Ban GR', '!SERVIR DEPOIS! Cortar em dois', ''
```

]

Comment: I've edited again my question, perhaps I can't explain what I need to archive. The print is a temporary output just to see if the loop works. The problem is building the second table. How to filter just the right lines?
In fact I've already done it long time ago but with a very poor quality and using a while loop and some variables as counters, but I'm not happy with the result. Even if it works is a waste of lines, I needed more than 80 lines to do that and since I'm learning Python I would like to pythonize my script as much as possible.

Comment: Partial success. The line with a normal name are considered and the newTable filled, but all the line containing name starting with '#' or '----' are ignored. Didn't figured out. I've uploaded my code and the result on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HXNauaY8) , much easy to read...

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/u8gg0Gsj), the 'elif i == len(fetch_lines)' condition is never reached.

Comment: Nope. It's still not printed then not added... I'm start to think my script is too complicated to resume it in a bunch of lines...

Comment: The last iteration works, but just since another '----' is present. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vEEucubU)

Comment: And doesn't work even if there is no '----' at all:  
  [(12853, 4430, 'Caprese GR', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 04'), (12854, 4430, '# Massa Integral', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 04')]
Result:
intr = Massa Integral
newTable:
[12853, 4430, 'Caprese GR', '', '']

Comment: You have working code. You now need to work through all the edge cases in your data.

Comment: Already on it. I'm starting to understand the flow. Night time here, tomorrow I'll try to close the circle. Thanks for now and good evening / night.

Comment: since I was quite impossible for me to solve all the issue I have with you code (too many variant to monitor) I wrote it again based on the idea of sorting and comparing two tables. Have a look on the last edit on my OP. Even if not 'pythonized', can you tell me what you think about this approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solved with the HUGE help of @Merlin, he drove me to the right direction but I needed to arrange the code. The big trick was to select the lines in DESC from table.

```
po_lines = '''SELECT pos_order_line.id, pos_order_line.order_id, product_template.name, pos_order_line.qty, product_template.pos_categ_id
           FROM public.pos_order_line, public.product_template
           WHERE pos_order_line.product_id = product_template.id AND  pos_order_line.order_id = %s
           AND (product_template.pos_categ_id != 5 AND product_template.pos_categ_id != 6)
           ORDER BY pos_order_line.id DESC'''

cur.execute(po_lines,[order]); fetch_lines = cur.fetchall()
instr = ''; newTable = []

for i, line in enumerate(fetch_lines):
    if line[2].startswith('#') or line[2].startswith('----'):
        if line[2].startswith('#'):
            instr = instr + line[2][2:]
        if line[2].startswith('----'):
            line_in = fetch_lines[i-1]
            extract_line = tuple([item[3] for item in newTable if line_in[0] in item])
            newTable = [t for t in newTable if t[0] != line_in[0]]
            instr = '!SERVIR DEPOIS!/' + extract_line[0]
            newTable.append((line_in[0], line_in[1], line_in[2], instr))
            instr = ''
    else:
        newTable.append((line[0], line[1], line[2], instr))
        instr = ''

for i,l in enumerate(newTable[::-1]):
    print i,l
```

Result:

```
0 (12811, 4419, 'Crudo GR', '')
1 (12812, 4419, 'Salame e Grana GR', '')
2 (12814, 4419, 'Nutella Ban GR', '!SERVIR DEPOIS!/Cortar em dois')
```

I'm sure my code could be better, but in the old version I needed more than 80 lines of code to archive that. That's a huge step forward for my Python knowledge.

Comment: I gave you the mark of correct question. Now, I think you did not considered I'm a newbie with Python. Thanks for trying but your last answer is far to be clear to what I need to do.   You told me to learn how to sort table when the table is correctly sortes as I need directly from query. How should I do that if not from query? The database is and always will be postgresql if is that what you mean.
What line (above and below) are you talking about? I'm really interested in because I'm here to learn, and as you've seen I'm trying, even doing wrong.

Comment: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/12/how-to-sort-table-by-columns-in-python/     Read this post then think how to sort your fetch_lines table on product so "#" and "----" are before products.... use code above , Then  If you need sort by product.id again.  The code  is  one line each.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Merlin but you forgot on thing:  the line_id order is mandatory. How do you manage the correct position after sorting by product? If you look to my code [here](http://pastebin.com/y0M25ZyV)  you'll clearly see what I mean and why I re-wrote the intere script. Really interesting in your version but I can't figure out how to implement it:  I'm sure I'm missing the point here.

Comment: First you sorted by product -- in the right order where you are processing  products. Then after you have added Intr,  Sort by  line_id.. then achrive

Comment: Is exactly what I did. But the intr is added to the wrong line... Is all in my code on pastebin. it shows [12812, 4419, 'Salame e Grana GR', '!SERVIR DEPOIS!Cortar em dois'] and not [12814, 4419, 'Nutella Ban GR', '!SERVIR DEPOIS!Cortar em dois']. Using the script with a more complex order showed another flow. It never reset Intr list.